# Report on Contacts with community users

Tags: reporting, customer-portal

I create the community users from Contact - Manage External User - Enable Customer user. Thus, I'm getting new record in Users. Is there any way I can build a report on all contacts who has community user created from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will create a Report on User Object where ContactId != '' .Please check the below screenshot[image]

> If a Community User is created then a User record has a contactId populated to link the contact with that User .